# Getting connection error from Flyway command line with DB2 drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, flyway

We are in the process of upgrading our database version from DB2 11.1.3 to DB2 11.5.6.  We have been using Flyway for 4 years for migrating our code.  The version we are using is 5.1.3 and it is working well, except it throws a warning the DB2 11.5 is not supported.

I have downloaded and tried to use Flyway 7.13.0 and 7.15.0 in our process but they both throw the following error

```
ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:db2://VAN-FCALLANDER:50000/TMLCLCUR:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;) for user 'TMWIN': [jcc][10214][10050][4.29.24] java.util.Properties object passed to java.sql.Driver.connect() cannot be overridden by URL: jdbc:db2://VAN-FCALLANDER:50000/TMLCLCUR:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42815
Error Code : -4461
Message    : [jcc][10214][10050][4.29.24] java.util.Properties object passed to java.sql.Driver.connect() cannot be overridden by URL: jdbc:db2://VAN-FCALLANDER:50000/TMLCLCUR:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815


Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10214][10050][4.29.24] java.util.Properties object passed to java.sql.Driver.connect() cannot be overridden by URL: jdbc:db2://VAN-FCALLANDER:50000/TMLCLCUR:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

According to IBM, the error being returned is from the way the parameter is set by Flyway.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=errors-errorcode-4461
I have tried using both the 11.1 (type3) driver and the 11.5 (type4) driver and both are throwing the same message.

Any idea how to get around this without updating the actual Flyway code the way IBM suggests?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Flyway code may need some change.

Check their [issues](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues) page and open a ticket if a ticket does not already exist there.

Otherwise there are possible workarounds for now.

In your specific case, the attribute appended to the URL triggers the exception so you can try:

(1) Change the flyway.url  to remove `:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true`

(2) Change the flyway config to supply this property via the `fltway.jdbcProperties` (or equivalent method) if that is enabled in your flyway version: `flyway.jdbcProperties.retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true` . See docs
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/jdbcProperties

or

(3) externally configure the connection property that you need via the IBM `db2dsdriver.cfg`. See the IBM Db2 documentation for details. The idea is that you can put all (or some of) the Data Source Name details and parameters into an XML file (`db2dsdriver.cfg`) and the Db2 driver will parse that at runtime to carry out your instructions.

or

(4) remove the property from the URL and suffer the absence of detailed messages on errors until the flyway code gets fixed.

Comment: Issue is here now: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3285 - many thanks!

Comment: Mao, thank you for the suggestions. I have implemented item 2 - config file update to include a flyway.jdbcProperties line which worked great in running my patches; however, that property is only available under the Teams version and does not provide me the version number when I request it. I'm hoping the issue Julia put in for this gets worked sooner rather than later

Comment: Update - 7.15 does not return the version number but 7.13 does.  Tested a couple of other switches in 7.13 and appears to be working correctly with the config property

Comment: I had a similar issue connecting to a DB2 db using DBeaver, encountering this same error and error codes.  Steps 1 and 2 effectively resolved the issue for me.